# Error al convertir de Int a Char en Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

me sale un error al intentar convertir de Int a Char con int.toChar(). En la consola, en vez de el numero que convertí a char se imprime un símbolo  (En la consola aparece como un rectángulo vació). La conversión a String si se realiza correctamente

```
var int: Int = 1
val string: String = int.toString()
val char: Char = int.toChar()
println(string) //Imprime 1
println(char)   //Imprime el símbolo
```

Si vuelvo a convertir el char a un Int, me sale el numero correctamente

```
int = char.toInt()
println(int) //Imprime 1
```

En mi codigo estoy haciendo algo simila a esto:

```
firstNumberString = firstNumberString.replaceFirst
('x', Random.nextInt(1,9 ).toChar())
//En vez de reemplazar la x con un numero, lo remplaza con el simbolo
var firstNumber = firstNumberString.toInt() //En esta linea envia un error
```

El error que me sale es este:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: ""    at
>   java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:638)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)

Answer (score 1):

El hex 1 representa el valor `SOH` que indica un inicio de encabezado segun el estandar [de los codigos `ASCII`](https://ascii.cl/), por lo que puede ser que el editor no tenga una forma de como representar ese caracter. Por ejemplo el hexagesimal 03 representa el fin de un texto por lo que el editor no tiene forma de representar tal caracter para lectura humana. Esto se extiende desde el HEX 0 hasta el 31.

Aqui te dejo los primeros 10 codigos ASCII:

```
00  NULL    (carácter nulo)
01  SOH     (inicio encabezado)
02  STX     (inicio texto)
03  ETX     (fin de texto)
04  EOT     (fin transmisión)
05  ENQ     (consulta)
06  ACK     (reconocimiento)
07  BEL     (timbre)
08  BS      (retroceso)
09  HT      (tab horizontal)
```

[Aqui la lista completa de los codigos ASCII](https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/)